# Classify LAS By Height tool is not yielding any results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, lidar, classification, las

The classify LAS by height tool (CLHT) in ArcGIS says that it will only reclassify LAS points with class codes of 0 or 1 (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/classify-las-by-height.htm). I have used the Change LAS Class Codes tool to reclassify class 3, 4, and 5 into 0. I then use the CLHT to enter in new class codes (>31 class codes) and respective heights. When the tool finishes, there are no new classes added to my LASD.

Where am I going wrong?

```
arcpy.ClassifyLasByHeight_3d(lasd, "GROUND", "32 1;33 2;34 4", "NONE", "false", "DEFAULT", "false")
```

Comment: Can you show *exactly* how you are running this tool? Does your LiDAR contain class 2 (ground) and optionally 8 (model key point)? Where does it say that only class 0 or 1 will be reclassified?

Comment: Have a look at the code sample http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/classify-las-by-height.htm it shows a list of lists, so "19 1;20 2;21 4;" should be [[19,1],[20,2],[21,4]].. what this is saying is anything less than 1 metre from ground classify as 19, 20 from 1 to 2 and between 2 and 4 metres as 21, is this congruent with your understanding of the parameters? Note that the maximum class limit for <= 1.3 is a *physical* limit; in ASPRS LAS v1.4 record format 6-10 the physical storage size is increased from 5 bits to 8 bits by moving the flags to their own byte.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success using class codes 19 through 31. I just read that only LAS version 1.0 and certain versions 1.4 support 31+. Looking at the table snippet below, I thought that reserved meant I couldn't use them. Turns out, it is all that can be used in my case.

```
arcpy.ClassifyLasByHeight_3d(lasd, "GROUND", "19 1;20 2;21 4;", "NONE", "false", "DEFAULT", "false")
```

[image]